# nautilus exiting with segmentation fault after upgrade

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, segmentation-fault

I upgraded to UBuntu 11.10 yesterday from 11.04. Everything went smoothly except the fact that nautilus wont start anymore. It exits with a segmentation fault. Any idea how to stop this from happening. ?

```
:~$ nautilus
Initializing nautilus-open-terminal extension
Initializing nautilus-gdu extension
** (nautilus:9741): DEBUG: SyncDaemon already running, initializing SyncdaemonDaemon object

(nautilus:9741): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_action_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_ACTION (action)' failed

(nautilus:9741): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_action_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_ACTION (action)' failed
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug, you should report that. [Here are details on how to do it.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: @jrg: thanks. I have already posted a bug in launchpad.

Comment: @Ubuntuser Link to the bug report?

Comment: Which bug? You should have put that in your question (though we'll likely close this, bug reports like this should be on the bug tracker)

Comment: @ubuntuser Ok, voting to close - if it turns out that it isn't a bug, feel free to flag to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the nautilus-open-terminal extension. This is causing problems right now and there is an open bug about it ([see here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-open-terminal/+bug/865115)).

This bug is now marked as fixed. If you are still experiencing the problem you may have another problem.