# Root password problems after upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I upgraded to 11.10 yesterday.

My Nautilus started to crash on load, looks like a known bug with remote terminal plugin [nautilus exiting with segmentation fault after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66188/nautilus-exiting-with-segmentation-fault-after-upgrade).

So I decided to uninstall it, but that was the beginning of my nightmare - my root password is changed.

Yes, I type in the right password, but auth fails!

I don't know what to do, I can't auth as root, which means I can't install/uninstall packages.

```
umpirsky@umpirsky:~$ su
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

Any idea? Please help.

UPDATE: I removed default keyring, but problem resists.

```
rm ~/.gnome2/keyrings/default.keyring
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo su - root`?

Comment: Can you try to boot into recovery mode and set a new password there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root account is disabled by default. A safer way to perform super-user actions is using the `sudo` command followed by your command.  Example : `sudo apt-get install clementine`.

But if you  really want to borrow the super-user account for a while, use `sudo su`. You can set the root account password there with `passwd` command. Example:

```
##Enter your account's password here##
nits@nits-workstation:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for nits: 
root@nits-workstation:/home/nits# passwd
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
root@nits-workstation:/home/nits# exit
exit

##once the password is set, log-in to the root account with the password you just set##
nits@nits-workstation:~$ su
Password: 
root@nits-workstation:/home/nits#
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Isn't this a security issue? I mean, everyone can change root pwd and take advantage of that. What is the point of this password then?

Comment: I had much shorter password before, and now passwd didn't let me enter that short pwd. Is this the password I enter when installing packages from software center, or updating the system?